# Android UpdateLayoutParams match_constraint not matching new given constraints

Tags: android, kotlin, android-constraintlayout, layoutparams

I have a task that I'm attempting to accomplish: to change constraints and update the layout programmatically when font scale configuration changes. Here I have the following code on a recyclerview element via view binding.

```
binding?.recyclerview?.apply {
     if(resources.configuration.fontScale >= 1.3f) {
                        val layoutParams = this.layoutParams as ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams
                        this.updateLayoutParams {
                            layoutParams.apply {
                                startToStart = LayoutParams.PARENT_ID
                                endToEnd = LayoutParams.PARENT_ID
                                width = ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_CONSTRAINT // <=Problem statement here
                                setMargins(UserInterfaceUtil().convertDPToPixel(30), 0, UserInterfaceUtil().convertDPToPixel(30), 0)
                            }
                        }
       }
     //...adapter code not given as not necessary to the problem
}

//functions convertDPToPixel not given because self explanatory
```

Previously, the constraints on the recyclerview were aligned not to the parent, but to another imageview inside the parent. Imageview is about 75dp margined from the start and end of parent; recyclerview is right below the imageview. XML follows:

```
     <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageview"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                android:contentDescription="image content description"
                android:scaleType="fitCenter"
                android:src="@drawable/src_image"
                android:visibility="visible"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/recyclerview"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/header_text" />

     <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/recyclerview"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                android:background="@color/grey"
                android:textColor="@color/darkGrey"
                android:textStyle="italic"
                app:layoutManager="androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/imageview"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/imageview"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/imageview" />
```

It is the line under the apply block for the recyclerview binding: width = LayoutParams.MATCH_CONSTRAINT, that isn't working; the view renders as if the constraint is still the previous edge of imageview; only when I use MATCH_PARENT instead of MATCH_CONSTRAINT, does it constrain properly, but why is that?

I have a working solution now, but this serves more as a question of why match_constraint programmatically didn't work vs match_parent on a ConstraintLayout LayoutParams element?

Answer (score 0):

*Imageview is about 75dp margined from the start and end of parent.*
According to your code, you set your imageView:

```
android:id="@+id/imageview" 
android:layout_width="0dp"
app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
```

It seems that this imageView is not 75dp margined from the start and end of parent. Here should be a

```
android:layout_marginHorizontal="75dp"
```

to build that margin

In your recyclerView you have:

```
app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/imageview"
app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/imageview"
```

It's kind of weird to set EndToStart and StartToEnd
at the same time. Try StartToStart and EndToEnd to see if it works